# Find the area of the shaded region under given curcumstances

Tags: geometry

> It is given that $ZV||XY,WZ=ZX,ZV=2a~~\text{and}~~ZX=2b.$
>   Find the area of the shaded region.

$a.)\dfrac{4ab}{2}\\
b.)\dfrac{8ab}{3}\\
\color{green}{c.)6ab}\\
d.)3ab\\$

[image]
$\quad$ 
I found that $XY=4a,\triangle WZY\sim \triangle WXY$  and $\dfrac{Area(\triangle WZV)}{Area(\triangle WXY)}=\dfrac14$

[image]

I am clueless. I look for a simple short way.
I have studied maths up to $12th$ grade.

Answer (score 1):

there are three right triangle with base $2a$ and height $2b$ that can fit in the shaded region. so the area is $3 \times2ab \sin \angle ZWV =  6ab \sin \angle ZWV$

without knowing what $\angle ZWV,$ we can only tell the ratio of the shaded region to the whole region; not the absolute value of either area.

Comment: @RK, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the area of $$\mathrm {Area}(\triangle WYX) = \frac{(4a)(4b)}{2} = \color{blue} {8ab} \,\, \text{and}\,\,  \mathrm{Area}(\triangle WVZ) = \frac{(2a)(2b)}{2} = \color{blue}{2 ab}$$

Now the shaded area is given by $$\mathrm {Area}(\triangle WYX) - \mathrm {Area}(\triangle WVZ)$$